# How do I get the latest post in a topic?

Tags: python, django

In the table, I want to show the latest post from that topic. My post model is called post. I have listed my code below.

**forum.html:**

```
          {% for category in categories %}
          <h5 class="blue-text">{{ category.title }}</h5>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Icon</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Latest Post</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            {% for topic in category.topic_set.all %}
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><i class="material-icons black-text">{{ topic.icon }}</i></td>
                <td><a href="/forum/topic/{{ topic.slug }}">{{ topic.title }} </a><br> <span class="grey-text">{{ topic.description }}</span></td>
                <td><a href="#!">post_title</a> <br> <span class="grey-text">post_author</span> <br> <span class="grey-text">post_created_at_timesince</span></td>
              </tr>
              {% empty %}
             <p>No topics in {{ category.title }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
          </table>
         {% empty %}
          <p>No categories.</p>
      {% endfor %}
```

**views.py:**

```
def forums(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    topics = Topic.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'forum.html', {'categories': categories, 'topics': topics})
```

If you need anymore details let me know.

Thanks,

Cameron.

Comment: This might help:[django-return-the-most-recent-date-of-a-record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772643/django-return-the-most-recent-date-of-a-record)

Comment: I put the wrong part of the views in but I have updated my answer. I don't think this would work because it would need to be in the HTML file.

Comment: You should have a **created_at** filed in your model.

Comment: I do have that field in the post model.

Comment: Now you can just have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314741/django-date-query-from-newest-to-oldest.

Comment: One more thing, if you have **Post** model then why are you not showing it and you are not using it in your **view**.

Comment: Okay, I just added it and trying something from the link you gave me.

Comment: Which **Django** and **Python** is this?

Comment: Can you add all related Models ?

Answer (score 0):

use `Topic.objects.order_by('-createtime')` to order them by createtime. If you don't have `createtime` in your field, you can use `-id` instead since the lastest topic has the largest id.

Comment: Nono, let me reword what I want to do. In the table, I want to show the latest post from that topic. My post model is called post.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in following way. You can change your view like this

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
def forums(request):
    topics = Topic.objects.all().order_by('-created_time')
    categories = Category.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch('topic_set', queryset=topics)
    return render(request, 'forum.html', {'categories': categories})
```

Above code snippet has two advantages:

- You will get latest post when you do `{% for topic in category.topic_set.all %}`.
- No extra query will execute for the above statement in the template.

You can add `topics` in the context if you are using at some other place also. For the given case, you do not need to send it in the context since you are getting the data from the category object.

If you require that you need to get latest post of category at multiple places, then you can also use `ordering` attribute in the meta class of the `topics` model.

You can find more details here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#ordering.

Comment: You don't need `.all()`, or `Prefetch`

Comment: I didn't get. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

To get the latest topic, you would do something like,

```
latest_topic = Topic.objects.order_by('-createtime')[-1]
```

or

```
latest_topic = Topic.objects.order_by('-id')[-1]
```